# Bike size advice Bianchi vs Cannondale

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, road, geometry, advice

I have been after a Bianchi Via Nirone 7 for more than one month and an half without much success. The main reason is that they don't produce many 47cm frames, while 47cm would be my optimal size. 
In the meantime, I ordered also a Cannondale CAAD Optimo 48cm and it fits fine, it's arrived in the shop ready to be brought home. But I really want the Bianchi. The problem is that the cheapest 47cm upgrade that I can do with a Bianchi is the double of my budget (Sempre Pro). 
At this stage I'm very exhausted and temped to go for a via Nirone 7 50cm frame even if is going to be slightly too big for me. 
I already quickly tried the 50cm via Nirone and the hip isn't very stable, I do some small overstretch.
If I go for a 50cm frame I need to cut 2cm in the seatpost (seatpin). So, the saddle would be slightly lower than handlebar. 
However, watching the geometries of Bianchi Via Nirone 7 50cm and Cannondale CAAD Optimo 48cm I don't see much big difference. 
My leg inseam is 70cm and height is 159cm.
**Bianchi Geometry:**
[image] 
**Cannondale Geometry:**
[image]
By the way, I did two 50 mile rides on Trek Domane, the first with a 47cm frame and the second with 50cm, and I felt more comfortable with 50cm. (But there wasn't any need of cutting the seatpost - I put it at the lowest position).
**Trek Geometry:**
[image]

Would would you do in my case? - Any advice?

Comment: I think this is purely a matter of opinion. You seem to want the Bianchi so much that you're prepared to put up with it not fitting very well. We can't know how much difference the size difference really makes to your body, so we can't rally give any objective advice.

Comment: Why can't your local bike shop order you a 47cm frame and build up the bike?  Are you limiting yourself to just in-store inventory?

Comment: I have a 40% discount if I go with that specific retailer. I spoke both with them and Bianchi and the problem is Bianchi, if I go with another retailer it won't change anything.

Comment: Wait, save up, get the bike you want.  You're going to own it and ride it for decades.  If you compromise on the essential things then you'll not love the bike as much.    You could potentially take the 40% discount and buy stuff like wheels and components, but search for the frame you want, regardless of the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you buy a complete bicycle, you just need to check two things: fitting and components.

Did you test the 2 bikes in the size you are discussing? The Bianchi should have a better frame, but nothing that can counterbalance the fact that a 50cm frame is too big.

Regarding "If I go for a 50cm frame I need to cut 2cm in the seatpost (seatpin)" I would go as far as to say that you are voiding warranty and therefore it does not make sense to do so on a new bike. In my opinion, neither on a used one.

Comment: Cutting down a seatpost is something that a bike shop will do quite often. Some bikes just don't have that much adjustment before the post bottoms out in the frame.

Comment: The Via Nirone 7 looks like a entry level aluminum frame to me. Why would anyone want to modify one instead of keep an already existing and fitting Cannondale?

Comment: @Carbonsideup : I understood the OP wanted to cut the seat tube. I hope I am wrong and you are right.

Comment: @ojs I am not sure if it is only marketing, but the Via Nirone 7 should have a Bianchi fork with carbon inserts that make the ride smoother. Does the fork alone justify the price and all the hassles of modifying it? I doubt, but a road test is necessary to have an opinion. Or maybe the OP just like the look of the Bianchi: I agree with you, a good custom paint job on a Cannondale is still preferrable (and probably cheaper) ...

Comment: @EarlGrey it is only marketing, and forks are fairly standard so you can just replace the one on Cannondale if you want.